Soft Latching Power Switch with extra input
I'm working on a project that will be battery and/or USB powered.
I would like to implement a soft power switch with the following functionality:

Pressing the power button for ~1s turns on the device when it is off.
Pressing the power button for ~1s turns off the device when it is on.
Plugging in a USB cable powers on the device (ignores button).
Unplugging the USB cable leaves the device powered. (Power button must be pressed to turn off)
Plugging in the USB cable when powered does nothing.

The project uses a PIC so use of GPIO and software is possible.
I have a nPowerGood open-drain signal from my li-ion charging IC which goes low when a USB power is available so I will be using this to determine if USB is plugged in.
I found the following circuit Here

If I connect the nPowerGood signal to the Auto-On/Off signal will this give me the funcitonality I need? I'm guessing I'll need some sort of pull-up as the signal is open-drain.
I've tried simulating the circuit above, as shown, and it always turns on regardless of what I do with the Auto-On/Off signal. Is there anything wrong with the circuit?
